# How to use jQuery to add static content to empty cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Here's a sample table

```
<table width="580" height="217" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="334">Website</td>
    <td width="246">Category</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    <td>Search Engine</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.gmail.com</td>
    <td>Web Mail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.xyz.com</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.amazon.com</td>
    <td>Shopping</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.website.com</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Two cells are empty in this table, how can i use jquery to add "not found" text in those empty cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('table td:empty').append('Not Found');
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/aJbZS/)**

Note that the selector `:empty` means no children, including text nodes, so watch how your html is laid out as laying out the opening and closing tags on new lines may introduce a text node child into what you consider an empty cell. A basic way to combat this could be to define our own selector expression

```
(function ($) {

    $.extend($.expr[':'],{
        reallyEmpty: function(elem) {
            return !elem.firstChild ||
               elem.firstChild.nodeType === 3 && !!/^\s|\n$/.test(elem.firstChild.textContent);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

and then use this

```
$('td:reallyEmpty').append('Not Found');
```

Comment: nice :) I wasn't aware of that syntax

Comment: Thank you very much, can you refer me some links where i can learn more about jquery in depth (other than jquery.com and w3cschools)

Comment: Some books I can recommend - jQuery in Action (http://manning.com/bibeault2/), jQuery cookbook (http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596159788). It's useful to download the book source too and go through that. Both books are good for learning good practices. Outside of that, I'd  look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749674/jquery-samples to begin. Set yourself up an RSS feed account and subscribe to those sites you find useful :)

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly do that :)

Comment: @RussCam nice with text, but if a cell contains only numbers/integer , the cell gets a 'Not Found' added. Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet I put together.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#tableid td').each(function()
{
  if($(this).html() == "") {
    $(this).html("Not Found"); 
  }
});

});

</script>
<table id="tableid" width="580" height="217" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="334">Website</td>
    <td width="246">Category</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    <td>Search Engine</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.gmail.com</td>
    <td>Web Mail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.xyz.com</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.amazon.com</td>
    <td>Shopping</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.website.com</td>
    <td ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('td').each(function(){
    if($(this).html()=='') 
       $(this).html('not found');
   });
```

Comment: Since all of your answers worked perfectly, Russ Cam snippet is very short and gets the job done.

Thank all for your support.